Powershell Out-Printer converts byte 1B to 2E
I want to send the "ESCc" command to my printer "PASS_PRT_1_300". ESC is the key (ASCII hex 1B). Now is send it in PowerShell:
"$([char]0x1B)$([char]0x63)" | Out-Printer -Name "PASS_PRT_1_300"

I am listening on ComPort 9 (where the printer is connected) and get "2e 63".
Why is it sending 2e instead of 1B?
Additional info's:
Windows 10
Printer driver: Generic /Text Only
Works if I make a direct connection on COM9 with vb.net and putty, and send "ESCc".

You're missing a closing bracket after 0x1B. Try "$([char]0x1B)$([char]0x63)"

I think the Baud rate is wrong.

@Theo sorry that was a copy mistake

@jdweng Baudrate is 115200. the commands arrive at the printer but wrong

Is baud rate what rate you are sending or the settings on the printer?  The two have to agree.

Both are 115200
